# generics in typescript not working properly?

Tags: generics, typescript

This should not compile, but it does:

```
var thingsWithName: { name: string }[] = [{ 'name': 'A' }, { 'name': 'B' }];

function doStuff <T extends { id: number }> (thingWithId: T): T {
    return thingWithId;
}

thingsWithName.map(doStuff);
```

as you can see `thingsWithName` don't have an `id`, so typescript compiler should warn about this when passing the `doStuff` to map.

Why does this typecheck? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3410).

The reason for this as outlined by the team is:

> Our assignability relation ignores generics and constraints in signatures. It just replaces all type parameters with any.
>
> ... we ignore generics because we believe taking them into account will be slow. And in general it leads to never-ending recursion if the signature was in a generic type. Because of this it seems not worth it.

In your code, note that a *non-generic* version will throw an error:

```
function doStuff(thingWithId: { id: number }): { id: number } {
    return thingWithId;
}

thingsWithName.map(doStuff); // error
```

And additionally note that since typescript uses structural typing to check the type, the following will happen with the *non-generic* version:

```
var arrayWithId    = [{ id: 2, myOtherProperty: "other value" }],
    arrayWithoutId = [{ noIdProperty: 2 }];

arrayWithId.map(doStuff);    // ok
arrayWithoutId.map(doStuff); // error
```